# For Cubic Graphs, does RCN=CN?

Tags: graph-theory

For an upcoming paper, lots of cubic graphs up to 30 nodes have been examined.  [Crossing Number Web Compute](http://crossings.uos.de/) and [QuickCross](http://www.flinders.edu.au/science_engineering/csem/research/programs/flinders-hamiltonian-cycle-project/quickcross.cfm) are two programs that can calculate crossing numbers.

For example, the [rectilinear crossing number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectilinearCrossingNumber.html) of the 16-cell graph is 8, but the [crossing number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCrossingNumber.html) is 6.

[image: 16 cell crossing number]

So far, with cubic graphs, up to 30 nodes, any time a graph has been verified to have a particular crossing number, a rectilinear embedding with that crossing number has been found.  Is that always the case?